# How to create a popup window with GLFW?

Tags: opengl, glfw

I was using GLFW for a recent project. I tried to create a dialog box, it is not topmost (other windows can come over it), but if you click on the mail window, the window will flash are require your focus by force, just like most of the eclipse windows (can't focus the window behind while the front window was opened).
I'm trying to implement this with GLFW, but it does not seem to have such supports. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is pretty hard. http://sourceforge.net/p/glfw/discussion/247562/thread/c0980c99/